serial number when sending contact form 7
I would like to insert a serial number when sending the form in order to use it as an ID for further processing. It would be nice if I could set the starting number myself.
for example: first sending is number 678 and the next one is always +1
The number should be visible when received.
I have no idea how can it work

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please try this it should work for you now.

Generate the shortcode for this input:
 function generate_serial_number() {
     $old_serial = get_option('cf7_serial_number', 678);
     $new_serial = $old_serial + 1;
     update_option('cf7_serial_number', $new_serial);
     return $new_serial;
 }

add_shortcode('cf7_serial_number', 'generate_serial_number');

Create read only a hidden serial number field in Contact Form 7 form
[text serial_number id:serial_number readonly default:cf7_serial_number]

Display the serial number in the email notifications

Edit the contact form under the Mail tab, and add Serial Number: [serial_number] to display the serial number in the received user email.


Now my script works when the form is submitted and the serial number will increase by 1, starting from your set value.

Hi Nilesh, thanks for your response. I put the code
bold `
function generate_serial_number() {
$old_serial = get_option('cf7_serial_number', 678);
$new_serial = $old_serial + 1;
update_option('cf7_serial_number', $new_serial);
return $new_serial;
}
add_shortcode('cf7_serial_number', 'generate_serial_number');´
in my function.php (Child Theme) and the field in my test formular. I get the mail but without the number. Where is my mistake?
Thanks in advance

please follow all the steps one by one. it will be 100% work for you.
